# Rails 3 Autocomplete Across Multiple Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

So I found some great info on Autocomplete for Rails 3, it looks really easy to use.  But I have a use case that doesnt fit and I need some advice.

I want to give the user the ability to add Products and Services to an Invoice through a simple form.  I'd like them to be able to type into the Item field and have it autocomplete from both Product.name and Service.name as a single set.

I'm thinking of trying to write a parent model that overlays all three, but I still don't think that solves my problem since I can't use a function in the autocomplete definition from what I understand.

Any advice on how I might try to accomplish this?  Even with the simple search examples that are out there they seem to be restricted to a single model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not opposed to introducing Redis into the mix, have a look at https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate -- From the README:

Soulmate is a tool to help solve the common problem of developing a fast autocomplete feature. It uses Redis's sorted sets to build an index of partially completed words and the corresponding top matching items, and provides a simple sinatra app to query them. Soulmate finishes your sentences.

Soulmate was designed to be simple and fast, and offers the following:

- Provide suggestions for multiple types of items in a single query (at SeatGeek we're autocompleting for performers, events, and venues)
- Results are ordered by a user-specified score
- Arbitrary metadata for each item (at SeatGeek we're storing both a url and a subtitle)

An item is a simple JSON object that looks like:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "term": "Citi Field",
  "score": 81,
  "data": {
    "url": "/citi-field-tickets/",
    "subtitle": "Flushing, NY"
  }
}
```

Where `id` is a unique identifier (within the specific type), `term` is the phrase you wish to provide completions for, `score` is a user-specified ranking metric (redis will order things lexicographically for items with the same score), and `data` is an optional container for metadata you'd like to return when this item is matched (at SeatGeek we're including a url for the item as well as a subtitle for when we present it in an autocomplete dropdown).

See Soulmate in action at [SeatGeek](http://seatgeek.com/).

If nothing else, maybe it'll give you some ideas on how to structure the data in a way that makes sense.

I did not write or have anything to do with soulmate.  It's just a library I discovered when trying to solve a similar problem.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If client-side autocomplete is an option (e.g. you have few products and services), you could go with JQuery autocomplete:

controller:

```
@keys = @categories.map { |x| x.name } + @entries.map { |x| x.description }
@autocomplete_categories = @keys.to_json.html_safe
```

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = <%= @autocomplete_categories %>;
    $("#auto").autocomplete( { source: data } );
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="auto" id="auto" />
```